# Display items according to lookup column

Tags: lookup-column

I need to display accordions. I have list called FAQ which contains a look up column `Category`. I need to display items FAQ according to Category using REST.

Can you tell me how I can apply filters ?

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('FAQ_Categories')/items?$select=*,Title,Description

_api/web/lists/getbytitle('FAQ')/items?$select=*,Category/Title&$expand=Category
```

Can you suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can expand and filter using

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('FAQ List Name')/items?$select=*,Category/Title&$expand=Category&$filter=Category/Title eq '<CategoryTitle>'
```